# Hiding navigation bar from login page in angular 4

Tags: angular

I had downloaded angular 4 template, In that they provide navigation elements in the app.component.html. i wanted to display only my login page as my default page and hide the navigation part.how to hide the navigation before login?

```html
<!---App.component.html-->[enter image description here][1]

<div class="bg-dark" *ngIf="layout == 'empty-view-1'"></div>
<sample-modals *ngIf="controller == 'notifications' && view == 'modals' "></sample-modals>
<right-sidebar-1 *ngIf="  layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></right-sidebar-1>
<navbar-1 *ngIf="  layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></navbar-1>
<top-navigation-1 *ngIf=" layout == 'top-navigation-1'"></top-navigation-1>
<jumbotron-2 *ngIf="  layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></jumbotron-2>
<top-navigation-2 *ngIf="layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></top-navigation-2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="left-sidebar-placeholder" *ngIf="layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></div>
   <left-sidebar-1 *ngIf=" layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2'"></left-sidebar-1>
   <div class="col main">
    <jumbotron-1 *ngIf=" controller != 'dashboards' && (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1')"></jumbotron-1>
    <div class="page">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<backdrops></backdrops>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what your service could look like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private userLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  getLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  getLoggedInValue(): boolean {
    return this.userLoggedIn.getValue();
  }

  setLoggedIn(val: string) {
    this.userLoggedIn.next(val);
  }
}
```

In your LoginComponent

```
import { LoginService } from 'login.service';

constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService
) {  }

// If user is logged in, set value to true
private setLoggedIn(value: boolean): void {
   loginService.setLoggedIn(value);
}
```

In your HomeComponent

```
import { LoginService } from 'login.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

private userLoggedIn: false;
private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService
) {  }


ngOnInit(): void {

    // get the current value
    this.subscription = this.loginService.getLoggedIn().subscribe(value => {
        this.userLoggedIn = value;
    });

}


ngOnDestroy(): void {

   if(this.subscription){
       this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }

}
```

And in your Template

```
<div class="bg-dark" *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (layout == 'empty-view-1')"></div>
<sample-modals *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (controller == 'notifications' && view == 'modals')"></sample-modals>
<right-sidebar-1 *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></right-sidebar-1>
```

Comment: @rina: Hope this helps.

Comment: Why make it an observable? Can't we use a normal boolean variable.

Comment: Yes you can but you shouldn't. You have to have a possibility to monitor the state of `userLoggedIn` all the time in order to immediately react on its change. Without an Observable you were supposed to let `HomeComponent` have some kind of scheduled watcher that pulls the state of `userLoggedIn` in a fixed interval, which was a pretty ugly approach compared to a Subscription to an Observable.

Comment: This is working- but for me navbar is showing only in home screen. I need to show navbar in all screens except login screen. How to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 11):

There is many ways of doing this. But i like this way by creating child routes and using "layouts".

example: create one component with only router-outlet

```
<!-- Base Layout-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then create a new component with router-outlet and the top navigation.

```
<!-- Site Layout -->
<!-- Top Navigation -->
<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>

<!-- content -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in your routes

```
const routing: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: BaseLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeComponent
        }
     ]
    }
];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's been said again and again, that using a central service to validate stuff like navbar visibility is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Define an additional variable that signals whether a user is logged in or not. Add this variable to your *ngIf-statements.

e.g.

```
private userLoggedIn: false;

<div class="bg-dark" *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (layout == 'empty-view-1')"></div>
<sample-modals *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (controller == 'notifications' && view == 'modals')"></sample-modals>
<right-sidebar-1 *ngIf="userLoggedIn && (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></right-sidebar-1>
```

As soon as the user is logged in, set this variable to true and your navigation elements will be shown.

Comment: it's hiding the navigation in the login page but when redirecting after login, it's not showing

Comment: Well, you should put this value into a service. Then set it to true in your login component and get the value in your home component.