# Login page in separate template in angular

Tags: angular, authentication

How can I have login page in a separate template from other components.

I saw answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/181176/tan  from post  [Hiding navigation bar from login page in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728144/hiding-navigation-bar-from-login-page-in-angular-4)
but I don't know how to change app.component

Answer (score 1):

You can have two `components` used as layouts: one containing your navigation bar etc. and another containing nothing.

Then, in your routing you could use them like this:

```
{
   path: '',
   component: FullLayoutComponent,
   children: [
   {
     path: 'myPage',
     loadChildren: './my-page/my-page.module#MyPageModule'
   }
 ]
},
{
   path: 'login',
   component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
   children:
   [
     {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule',
     }
   ]
 }
```

Here `FullLayoutComponent` is your `component` containing the nav bar etc. and `SimpleLayoutComponent` the `component` containing nothing.

Don't forget to put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in each component's template.